# Shall a question asking "How to get X" be closed as duplicate of a question asking "Is it good practice to do Y to get X"?

Tags: discussion

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48951580/returning-const-value-from-arithmetic-operator-overload-with-move-assignment) asks: *how could I make the expression `a+b=c` ill-formed in C++?*

In the comments, a user proposes as a solution [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12759340/should-i-use-lvalue-reference-qualifiers-for-assignment-operators) which asks :*Is it good practice to declare a ref overload of the assignment operator to make `a+b=c` ill-formed?*

The second question contains the answer of the first. Then the answers to the second question discuss if it is a good practice.

Should the first question be closed as a duplicate of the second?

Comment: A comment to OP may be appropriate as they will likely disregard the Q and only skim read the A's looking for their solution.

Comment: Happens all the time, and I do vote to close on the basis that all information is there. Thinking each time that this fact is clear enough, I leave the comment only after they object to the close vote ;)

Comment: @GSerg: Unless the question really is an exact duplicate, rather than being *answered by* the linked question, you should leave a comment to explain why it's a duplicate or what the key point is.

Comment: I think there is something somewhere in the guidelines along the lines of *"assume a reasonably competent reader (in the absence of evidence to the contrary)"* so if a reasonably competent reader should be able to see how the two are connected, I'd say this is fine. Users who demonstrate that they don't know what they are doing are harder to help, but then marking as a duplicate and leaving a comment to explain what to make of it would seem like the way to go (unless the user is so incompetent as to render the question worthy of closing for other reasons).

Answer (score 5):

No I don't think the linked question should be closed as a duplicate to that post.

The linked question contains a discussion about examples from some old C++ book, which is a unique aspect not addressed by the duplicate, and also something that future readers using the same book would be interested in.

There's potential for a good answer by a C++ guru here. Did the book make sense in the first place? Has the book gone outdated because of C++*nn*?